# What is this model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, spin-models, critical-phenomena

Consider the following model in classical statistical mechanics. Take a finite box $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^d$ and consider the field $\phi:\Lambda\to[-1,1]$ whose Gibbs measure is given by $$ \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\phi):=\frac{\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\beta\sum_{x\in\Lambda}\sum_{y\sim x}\phi_x\phi_y\right)}{\left(\prod_{x\in\Lambda}\int_{\phi_x\in[-1,1]}\mathrm{d}\phi_x\right)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\beta \sum_{x\in\Lambda}\sum_{y\sim x}\phi_x\phi_y\right)}\prod_{x\in\Lambda}\mathrm{d}\phi_x\,. $$

1. Does this model have a name? Has it been studied?
2. I am trying to ascertain if this model has a phase transition in various dimensions $d$, i.e., if there is some $\beta_c<\infty$ such that above it the two point function $$ \mathbb{E}\left[\phi_x\phi_y\right] $$ is polynomial decaying or constant and below it, it is exponentially decaying. Has this been studied? Is there a simple argument, e.g., for the non-existence of a phase transition in $d=2$?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, so I doubt I could answer the question. But for those who might, it may be helpful to know where you found the model and in what context. Did you come up with it, or is there a reference?

Comment: @G.Smith $y\sim x$ means that $y$ is a neighbor of $x$. The denominator is just the partition function, the first "factor" denotes simply integration over all spins in $\Lambda$, the second "factor" being the integrand.

Comment: @G.Smith : It's a ferromagnetic model (larger Boltzmann weight when neighboring spins have the same sign). If you wish, there is a minus sign in the Hamiltonian that is cancelled by the minus sign in the Boltzmann weight.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: I don't see why this was closed. The OP stated completely explicitly the probability measure.  This **completely** characterizes the model. In particular, the Hamiltonian and single-spin space can be extracted immediately.

Comment: If the some of the clarifications made in the comments were added to the question, it would be suitable for reopening in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **continuous spin Ising model**. It has a phase transition at large $\beta$ in any dimension greater or equal to $2$; see [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01941973), for instance.

It is also known as the **infinite spin Ising model**. It was first introduced by Griffiths in [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1665005).

See also [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0550321300004594) for a more geometrical way of analyzing this model (through a generalization of the Fortuin-Kasteleyn random cluster representation).